# Chess Architecture

Tags: java, swing, awt, chess

I am currently developing a chess game but have made the mistake of putting all my Java code in one .java file.

I need help cutting up my code into more manageable chucks. Could someone show me how to take out all the piece movements and put them in a separate file which then links back in to the main file? I have tried myself but I end up just breaking the game.

Here is the full messy Java file currently I only have some of the pieces coded up so I thought I would not go further without solving the terrible architecture here.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessProject extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int initialX;
    int initialY;
    JPanel panels;
    JLabel pieces;

    public ChessProject() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white);
            }
        }

        // Setting up the Initial Chess board.
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhitePawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(1);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(6);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(2);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(5);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(3);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(4);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("WhiteRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(7);
        panels.add(pieces);
        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackPawn.png"));
            panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(i);
            panels.add(pieces);
        }
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(56);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(57);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKnight.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(62);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(58);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackBishup.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(61);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackKing.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(59);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackQueen.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(60);
        panels.add(pieces);
        pieces = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BlackRook.png"));
        panels = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(63);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }

    private Boolean piecePresent(int x, int y) {
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Check if a piece is a Black piece.
    private Boolean checkWhiteOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    //Check if a piece is a White piece.

    private Boolean checkBlackOponent(int newX, int newY) {
        Boolean oponent;
        Component c1 = chessBoard.findComponentAt(newX, newY);
        JLabel awaitingPiece = (JLabel) c1;
        String tmp1 = awaitingPiece.getIcon().toString();
        if (((tmp1.contains("White")))) {
            oponent = true;
        } else {
            oponent = false;
        }
        return oponent;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        initialX = e.getX();
        initialY = e.getY();
        startX = (e.getX() / 75);
        startY = (e.getY() / 75);
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Boolean success = false;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        String tmp = chessPiece.getIcon().toString();
        String pieceName = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 4));
        Boolean validMove = false;

//Pawn Moves
//White Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("WhitePawn")) {
            if (startY == 1) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 6) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == 1) {
                                if (startY == 6) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
//Black Pawn
        if (pieceName.equals("BlackPawn")) {
            if (startY == 6) {
                if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) || ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                    if ((((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -2)) {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY() + 75)))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ((!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY())))) {
                            validMove = true;
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            } else {
                int newY = e.getY() / 75;
                int newX = e.getX() / 75;
                if ((startX - 1 >= 0) || (startX + 1 <= 7)) {
                    if ((piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) && ((((newX == (startX + 1) && (startX + 1 <= 7))) || ((newX == (startX - 1)) && (startX - 1 >= 0))))) {
                        if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            validMove = true;
                            if (startY == 1) {
                                success = true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if ((startX == (e.getX() / 75)) && ((e.getY() / 75) - startY) == -1) {
                                if (startY == 2) {
                                    success = true;
                                }
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Pawn Moves
        //Knight Moves
        //White Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteKnight")) {

            // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

            // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
            // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {

                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Knight Code
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackKnight")) {

                    // next we need to get the new coordinates for where the piece is being dropped.
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;

                    // We need to make sure that the piece is being put back on the board...if its not being on
                    // the board why would we want to check anything else!
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                if (((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY + 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY + 1)) || ((newX == startX + 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX - 1) && (newY == startY - 2)) || ((newX == startX + 2) && (newY == startY - 1)) || ((newX == startX - 2) && (newY == startY - 1))) {
                    validMove = true;

                    if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                        if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                            if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                validMove = true;
                            } else {
                                validMove = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Knight Code
        //Bishop Code
        //White Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("WhiteBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("White")) {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        } //Black Bishup
        else if (pieceName.contains("BlackBishup")) {
            int newY = e.getY() / 75;
            int newX = e.getX() / 75;
            boolean inTheWay = false;
            int distance = Math.abs(startX - newX);
            if (((newX < 0) || (newX > 7)) || ((newY < 0) || (newY > 7))) {
                validMove = false;
            } else {
                validMove = true;
                if (Math.abs(startX - newX) == Math.abs(startY - newY)) {
                    if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX < 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX + (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY - (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if ((startX - newX > 0) && (startY - newY < 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
                            if (piecePresent((initialX - (i * 75)), (initialY + (i * 75)))) {
                                inTheWay = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (inTheWay) {
                        validMove = false;
                    } else {
                        if (piecePresent(e.getX(), (e.getY()))) {
                            if (pieceName.contains("Black")) {
                                if (checkBlackOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (checkWhiteOponent(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                                    validMove = true;
                                } else {
                                    validMove = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            validMove = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else { // the move that is being tried is not a diagonal move...
                    validMove = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //End of Bishup Code


//Changes to new pawn Piece and Validates Move

    if(!validMove){
        int location=0;
        if(startY ==0){
            location = startX;
        }
        else{
            location  = (startY*8)+startX;
        }
        String pieceLocation = pieceName+".png";
        pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(pieceLocation) );
        panels = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
        panels.add(pieces);
    }
    else{
        if(success){

            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);

                String promoteTo;
                do {
                    promoteTo = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Promote Pawn to :", "Pawn Promotion",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        new String[]{"Queen", "Bishup", "Knight", "Rook"}, "Queen");
                } while (promoteTo == null);
                String newPiece = null;
                int location = 0;
                if (pieceName.contains("White"))
                {
                    location = 56 + (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "White"+promoteTo;
                }
                else
                {
                    location =  (e.getX()/75);
                    newPiece = "Black"+promoteTo;
                }

                pieces = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(newPiece+".png") );
                parent = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(location);
                parent.add(pieces);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        else{
            if (c instanceof JLabel){
                Container parent = c.getParent();
                parent.remove(0);
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            else {
                Container parent = (Container)c;
                parent.add( chessPiece );
            }
            chessPiece.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessProject();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that asking for code to be written is off-topic for Code Review. Answers provide advice, and may or may not include code. Please do not pester reviewers into writing code for you, if they haven't done so voluntarily.

Comment: What you *really* need is a [tutorial on classes in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: This has also been posted at Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779966/chess-code-split

Answer (score 11):

You should separate the modelling of the game, board and pieces from the display components. (google: model-view-controller, separation of concerns).

- You can create a `Game` class that models the game and the game-logic
- You can create a `Board` class that models the internal state of the chess-board.
- You can create a `Piece` class and subclasses for each `Piece`, e.g. `Rook`, `King`
- You can create a `Display` class that uses this model to display a `Board`

All the UI interaction can be done in the `Display` class.
All the game-logic should be in the `Game` class and should ask stuff from the `Board`. For example the `check..` methods should go there.
The movement checks can go into the `Piece` subclasses.

Answer (score 10):

Lets start by naming:

1. It should be clear that the `frame` doesn't have the name of the project, so instead of the class `ChessProject` you can call this class `ChessFrame` instead.
2. It's all about separation of concerns, you should have seperate class that does the Chess logic and one that does the `UI` and use composition to use its features

   ```
   class ChessBoard{
      ...
   } 

   class ChessBoardFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
     private ChessBoard chessBoard;
   }
   ```
3. Access modifiers are important: always try to hide your fields by declaring them `private`.

   ```
   private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
   private JPanel chessBoard;
   private JLabel chessPiece;
   ```
4. Don't use `magic numbers` in your code, extract them to constants instead.

   ```
    final int sideSize = 600;
    Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(sideSize, sideSize);
   ```

   Especially in loops where the boundaries are hard to understand, don't assume the code maintainer is a professional chess player.

   ```
   for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
    // extract those boundaries to constants 
   }
   ```
5. Delete unnecessary code, replace

   ```
   if (((tmp1.contains("Black")))) {
       oponent = true;
   } else {
       oponent = false;
   }
   return oponent;
   ```

   By

   ```
   return temp1.contains("Black");
   ```

Comment: can you show me a move detailed example of say how i would go about separating the pieces from the main body of code ?

Comment: @Jamiex304 http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Answer (score 3):

Here are two simple suggestions for improving code structure:

1. Create base class for chess pieces `abstract class Piece` and subclasses for each of the pieces (e.g. `class King extends Piece`). Each class can then contain code that applies to the piece it represents. This will make it easier to maintain game logic in smaller self-contained chunks of code.

   ```
   class Position { /* ... */ }
   abstract class Piece
   {
       abstract boolean canMove(Position from, Position to);
       protected List<Piece> attackedBy() { return null; }   // shared code example
   }
   class King extends Piece
   {
       boolean canMove(Position from, Position to) { return false; }
   }
   ```
2. Separate UI code from game logic. Put UI code into View classes. Make a view object for each piece on the board. Make game Controller class for working with both view objects and game state. Keep game state in Model class. Search for MVC to get further details about this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is procedural, yet still very elegant. I'll attempt to walk through a refactoring process to help you to think more object oriented. Also, be sure to include all of your classes within a package when you're programming in java.

The simplest change to start with is to begin isolating [responsibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Move the `public static void main` method into its own class. This will form the [aggregate root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks_of_DDD) of our program once we separate out the business concerns from display concerns in the classes later on. For now, let's just copy exactly what you have.

**jamiex304/chessgame/App.java**

```
package jamiex304.chessgame;    
/* Imports ... */

public class App {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ChessProject();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }        
}
```

Next, let's begin extracting the objects from the system. Anything named as a noun is a likely candidate for becoming an object. Each object will be defined as a `class` in its own file. Because we are not yet separating the view from the behaviors, we'll keep the classes in the `jamiex304.chessgame` package for now.

**jamiex304/chessgame/Board.java**

```
package jamiex304.chessgame;
/* Imports ... */
public class Board extends JPanel {

}
```

**jamiex304/chessgame/Square.java**

```
package jamiex304.chessgame;
/* Imports ... */
public class Square extends JPanel {

}
```

**jamiex304/chessgame/Piece.java**

```
package jamiex304.chessgame;
/* Imports ... */    
public abstract class Piece extends JLabel {

}
```

Notice that we've only extracted a single abstract `Piece` at this point. There are 6 distinct pieces in a chess set. Each have special features such as shape and maneuvers, but we want to focus on the common features or interface of a `Piece` at this level.

Now, let's focus on moving the `Board` code from `ChessProject`. Again, we will focus on the isolating responsibilities.

1 Rather than implementing the `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` interfaces, we'll encapsulate a `MouseAdapter` and delegate the mouse input responsibility to it. The current mouse interface methods are doing too much as can be seen by the number of global state variables they reference. We'll leave the definition of the `MouseAdapter` methods blank for now.

2 We'll keep the construction logic in the constructor, but separate the square initialization to it's own private method.

**jamiex304/chessgame/Board.java**

```
package jamiex304/chessgame/Board.class;
/* Imports ... */
public class Board extends JPanel {
    private class BoardMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    }

    public Board() {
        BoardMouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new BoardMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        initializeSquares();
    }

    private void initializeSquares() {
        for (int row = 1; row <= 8; row++) {
            for (char column = 'a'; column <= 'h'; column++) {
                Color squareColor = (row % 2 == column % 2) ? Color.white : Color.gray;
                Square square = new Square(squareColor);
                add(square);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I changed the loop for initializing the squares a little. The places on a chessboard are not just 64 squares, they are 8 rows and 8 columns of squares which are normally designated by an alphanumeric pair. Let the code reflect what we are virtualizing.

And we can see that square needs a color attribute. A square must have a color and will not change color after creation, so it belongs in the `Square` constructor. We'll update the class to match

**jamiex304/chessgame/Square.java**

```
package jamiex304.chessgame;
/* Imports ... */    
public class Square extends JPanel {
    Square(Color squareColor) {
        this.setBackground(squareColor);
    }
}
```

*If you have found this answer to be helpful so far, then you have work to do. Follow along with your own project this far and continue pulling the code from your `ChessProject.java` file into the `Square.java` class to set up a square as well as the `Piece.java` class. Post what you arrive at as another code review and I will continue there.*